Get request from different CRUD controller
good evening everyone, I have a problem retrieving a parameter from another CRUD controller with EasyAdmin 4
$url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(SecondCrudController::class)
            ->setAction(Action::NEW)
            ->set('id', $id)
            ->generateUrl();
        $actions->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, 
            Action::new('actionIdentification', 'Action label')
            ->linkToUrl($url)
        );

how can I retrieve the 'id' parameter in SecondCrudController?
THANKS
I tried dd($resquest) and I don't see how to get the 'id' parameter.
